# How do I add spacing between the text and the edge to make it in the middle

Tags: flutter

How do i add spacing between the text and the edge of the screen and make both the name and email aligned

[my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNDoU.png)

This is my current code and it shows the information left justified with the line
'crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,' but i want to align the words name and email in the middle of the page how do I do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1rGg.png)

Comment: You could take two row inside the column and inside the row do mainAxisalignment as spacebetween and for the column do crossAxis as center

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @rabbiteatingmoney. Uploading code snippets as images [is frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) here. If you would edit your question accordingly, the community will appreciate it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is a handy guide for markdown formatting, if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Use row please like this

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,///Play with this or any other
children:[
   Text('Your text'),
   const SizedBox(width:40.0),//You can change this value to whatever you like
   Text('Your text'),
  ]
),
```

Please prefer pasting a real code instead of a screenshot it makes answering easier

Comment: okay! i tried using row but an error saying 
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.
what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Where exactly??

Answer (score 0):

You can user Sizebox or use Align widget

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Row` widget to display widgets in horizontal view.

Example:

```html
Row(
children:[
   Text('Hello:'),
   const SizedBox(width:20),
   Expanded(child: Text('World')),
  ]
),
```